# Python linear regression model (Pandas, statsmodels) - Value error: endog exog matrices size mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

A friend of mine asked me about this linear regression code and I also couldn't solve it, so now it's my question as well.

Error we are getting:
***ValueError: endog and exog matrices are different sizes***

When I remove "Tech" from ind_names then it works fine. This might be pointless but for the sake of eliminating syntax error possibilities I tried doing it.

Tech and Financial industry labels are not equally distributed in the DataFrame so maybe this is causing a size mismatch? But I couldn't debug any further so decided to ask you guys.

It'd be really nice to get some confirmation on the error and solution ideas. Please find code below.

```
    #We have a portfolio constructed of 3 randomly generated factors (fac1, fac2, fac3). 
#Python code provides the following message 
#ValueError: The indices for endog and exog are not aligned

import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import rand
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

fac1, fac2, fac3 = np.random.rand(3, 1000) #Generate  random factors

#Consider a collection of hypothetical stock portfolios
#Generate randomly 1000 tickers
import random; random.seed(0)
import string
N = 1000
def rands(n):
  choices = string.ascii_uppercase
  return ''.join([random.choice(choices) for _ in range(n)])


tickers = np.array([rands(5) for _ in range(N)])
ticker_subset = tickers.take(np.random.permutation(N)[:1000])

#Weighted sum of factors plus noise

port = pd.Series(0.7 * fac1 - 1.2 * fac2 + 0.3 * fac3 + rand(1000), index=ticker_subset)
factors = pd.DataFrame({'f1': fac1, 'f2': fac2, 'f3': fac3}, index=ticker_subset)

#Correlations between each factor and the portfolio 
#print(factors.corrwith(port))
factors1=sm.add_constant(factors)


#Calculate factor exposures using a regression estimated by OLS
#print(sm.OLS(np.asarray(port), np.asarray(factors1)).fit().params)

#Calculate the exposure on each industry
def beta_exposure(chunk, factors=None):
    return sm.OLS(np.asarray(chunk), np.asarray(factors)).fit().params


#Assume that we have only two industries – financial and tech

ind_names = np.array(['Financial', 'Tech'])
#Create a random industry classification 

sampler = np.random.randint(0, len(ind_names), N)
industries = pd.Series(ind_names[sampler], index=tickers, name='industry')
by_ind = port.groupby(industries)



exposures=by_ind.apply(beta_exposure, factors=factors1)
print(exposures)
#exposures.unstack()

#Determinate the exposures on each industry
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Understanding the error message:

> ValueError: endog and exog matrices are different sizes

Okay, not too bad. The endogenous matrix and exogenous matrix are of different sizes. And the module provides this [page](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/endog_exog.html) which tells that **endogenous are the factors within the system** and **exogenous are factors outside it**.

#### Some debugging

Check what shapes we are getting for our arrays. To do that we need to take apart that oneliner and print of the `.shape` of the arguments or maybe print the first handful of each. Also, comment out the line throwing the error. So there, we discover that we get:

```
chunk [490]
factor [1000    4]
chunk [510]
factor [1000    4]
```

Oh! There it is. We were expecting factor to be chunked too. It should be [490 4] the first time and [510 4] the second time. Note: since the categories are assigned randomly, this will differ each time.

So basically we have just too much info in that function. We can use the chunk to see what factors to chose, filter the factors to be just those and then everything will work.

#### Looking over the function definitions in the docs:

```
class statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS(endog, exog=None, missing='none', hasconst=None, **kwargs)
```

We are just passing two arguments and the rest are optional. Let's look at the two we are passing.

> endog (array-like) – 1-d endogenous response variable. The dependent variable.
>
> exog (array-like) – A nobs x k array where nobs is the number of observations and k is the number of regressors...

Ah, `endog` and `exog` again. `endog` is 1d array-like. So far so good, shape `490` works. `exog` **nobs?** Oh, its number of observations. So it's a 2d array and in this case, we need shape `490` by `4`.

#### This specific issue:

`beta_exposure` should be:

```
def beta_exposure(chunk, factors=None):
    factors = factors.loc[factors.index.isin(chunk.index)]
    return sm.OLS(np.asarray(chunk), np.asarray(factors)).fit().params
```

The issue is that you are applying beta_exposures to each part of the list (it is randomized, so let's say 490 elements for `Financial` and 510 for `Tech`) but `factors=factors1` always gives you 1000 values (the `groupby` code doesn't touch that).

See http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html and http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/endog_exog.html for the references I used researching this.

Comment: Thanks for such a descriptive answer! So I guess it's confirmed the different amounts of industry labels caused the value error. Now it'd be nice to know how to better write this code and eliminate the error.

Comment: Glad to help. I think you'd still get the same error if it was split `500` by `500`. That's not the issue but rather that you are sending in about `500` values but `1000` factors (you are sending in one group at a time but all the factors every time). However, if you do want to make it `500` by `500`, I tried doing `sampler = [0] * 500 + [1] * 500` and then `random.shuffle(sampler)`. If my answer helped, please select it. Thanks! By the way, I made it so descriptive in case others run into the same error message. While you may know some of what I said already, it may be new to someone else.

Comment: I wanted to confirm my answer so I just added in the line you are missing.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks again! it was a superb answer. Thanks for the 500/500 clarification as well. I don't think endog and exog are better explained anywhere else on the web, not even on the official sites.